# Android Automation of Regression Testing using Robotium

Tags: android, junit, robotium, android-testing

I have generated a robotium test case and successfully tested the same on real device. Now, i like to know how can i run the same test case (Class that extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2) repeatedly.

Please let me know if any code sample for doing the same.

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't make any sense - running the same junit test repeatedly. What are your trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this 2 ways ..

**Method 1** - Same Test case can be called many times from a class that extends InstrumentationTestRunner.

```
import junit.framework.TestSuite;
import android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner;
import android.test.InstrumentationTestSuite;

public class MediaFrameworkTestRunner extends InstrumentationTestRunner {

    @Override
    public TestSuite getAllTests() {
        InstrumentationTestSuite suite = new InstrumentationTestSuite(this);

        suite.addTestSuite(MainActivityTest.class);
        suite.addTestSuite(MainActivityTest.class);
        return suite;
    }

    @Override
    public ClassLoader getLoader() {
        return MediaFrameworkTestRunner.class.getClassLoader();
    }
}
```

**Method 2** - Add a loop statement inside the testRecorded() method